# ERROR 13 !! Type mismatch

Tags: vba, excel

ANY IDEA ??? I don't know why there's a type error especially that i've changed the type of both cells

```
Cells(i, 7).NumberFormat = "@"
Workbooks("template.xls").Worksheets("Introduction").Cells(j, 21).NumberFormat = "@"
If Left(Cells(i, 7), 13) = Workbooks("template.xls").Worksheets("Introduction").Cells(j, 21).Value  
.
.
.
```

Code from comments:

```
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Integer
For j = 5 To derlig
    For i = 2 To 4000
        Cells(i, 2).NumberFormat = "@"
        Workbooks("template.xls").Worksheets("Introduction").Cells(j, 21).NumberFormat = "@"
        Workbooks("Cat export.xls").Worksheets("Items").Activate
        If Left(Cells(i, 2), 13).Value = Workbooks("template.xls").Worksheets("Introduction").Cells(j, 21).Value Then
            Workbooks("Cat export.xls").Worksheets("Items").Cells(i, 3) = Right(Workbooks("Cat export.xls").Worksheets("Items").Cells(i, 2), 5)
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Comment: Can you give an example of what values are in `Cells(i, 7)` and `Workbooks("template.xls").Worksheets("Introduction").Cells(j, 21)`? Also just to double check, `Workbooks("template.xls")` is open, yes?

Comment: Add the code `debug.print Left(Cells(i,7),13) & " = " & debug.print Workbooks("template.xls").Worksheets("Introduction").Cells(j, 21).Value` then press ctrl+G and see if the results are as expected.

Comment: Add the workbook and worksheet you want to check in the left part of your `If` statement, like you did on the right side.

Comment: besides the questions asked by people above, how have you declared `i` and `j`? and what are their values?

Comment: @Jordan 

Cells(i,7) = BF-1CI-10200-00033
Workbooks("template.xls").Worksheets("Introduction").Cells(j, 21) = BJ-1CI-35020-

Comment: @jcarroll didn't get your point of view

Comment: @SiddharthRout j as integer and i as long

Comment: and how are you assigning values to i and j?

Comment: here's my code @SiddharthRout
`Dim i As Long
Dim j As Integer
 For j = 5 To derlig
 For i = 2 To 4000
 Cells(i, 2).NumberFormat = "@"
 Workbooks("template.xls").Worksheets("Introduction").Cells(j, 21).NumberFormat = "@"
 Workbooks("Cat export.xls").Worksheets("Items").Activate
 If Left(Cells(i, 2), 13).Value = Workbooks("template.xls").Worksheets("Introduction").Cells(j, 21).Value Then
  Workbooks("Cat export.xls").Worksheets("Items").Cells(i, 3) = Right(Workbooks("Cat export.xls").Worksheets("Items").Cells(i, 2), 5)
 End If
 Next
 Next`

Comment: At the time of the error what is the value if i and j?

Comment: What line is the error on?  I'm guessing it's before `Left(Cells(i, 2), 13).Value`, because that's a run-time error 424 (Object required), not a run-time error 13.

Comment: @Comintern absolutely I don't know why :/

Comment: @IkrameBahhar - `Left` returns a `Variant`, not an object.  What line is the run-time error 13 on?

Answer (score 2):

The error is happening because you are not qualify **all** of your objects, so if any workbook or worksheet is active other than what you may expect, the code may not perform correctly.

It's **best practice** to **always** qualify objects in VBA and work directly with them.

See below:

```
Dim wbMyWB as Workbook, wbTemplate as Workbook
Set wbMyWB = Workbooks("myWB.xlsx") 'change as needed
Set wbTemplate = Workbooks("template.xls")

Dim wsMyWS as Worksheet, wsIntro as Worksheet
Set wsMyWS = wbMyWB.Worksheets("Sheet1") ' change as needed
Set wsIntro = wbTemplate.Worksheets("introduction")

'....
Dim rMyRange as Range, rIntro as Range

'assumes i and j are properly set to long or integer (or variant (hopefully not) type 
'ideally i and j are both set to integer
rMyRange = wsMyWs.Cells(i,7) 
rIntro = wsIntro.Cells(j,21)

rMyRange.NumberFormat = "@"
rIntro.NumberFormat = "@"

If Left(rMyRange,13).Value = rIntro.Value Then 
   'condition satisfied
End If
```

Comment: Type mismatch for this?

Comment: Agreed @SiddharthRout - I may have jumped the gun and the variables `i` and `j` should definitely be considered in terms of how they are set. I will amend or delete once more feedback comes from OP.

Comment: @IkrameBahhar - what error do you get and on what line?

Comment: @ScottHoltzman now I get the 424 error in the if line 
`Dim i As Long
Dim j As Integer
 For j = 5 To derlig
 For i = 2 To 4000
 Cells(i, 2).NumberFormat = "@"
 Workbooks("template.xls").Worksheets("Introduction").Cells(j, 21).NumberFormat = "@"
 If Left(Cells(i, 2), 13).Value = Workbooks("template.xls").Worksheets("Introduction").Cells(j, 21).Value Then
  Workbooks("Cat export.xls").Worksheets("Items").Cells(i, 3) = Right(Workbooks("Cat export.xls").Worksheets("Items").Cells(i, 2), 5)
 End If
 Next`

Comment: @IkrameBahhar - you still have not qualified all the objects. ...  for example `Cells(i,2).NumberFormat = "@"` ... or `Left(Cells(i, 2), 13).Value`